# Ruby. How to sort by a specific column in a grid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default sorting using jqGrid and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471972/default-sorting-using-jqgrid-and)

```
def format_quote_grid!
Quote.grid.update({
:title => "Quotes",
:pager => true,
:search_toolbar => :hidden,
:resizable => false,
:height => :auto,
:except => [:contacts],
:rows_per_page => 10}) { |grid|
  grid.column :id, :label => "Number", :width => 50#, :proc => lambda {|record| link_to record.number, quote_path(record) }
  grid.column :job_name, :width => 140, :proc => lambda {|record| link_to record.job_name, quote_path(record) }
  grid.column :category, :width => 60
  grid.column :needs_installation, :width => 60
  grid.column :contact_id, :hidden => true
  grid.column :business_id, :hidden => true
  grid.column :contact_name, :label => "Contact", :width => 100, :sortable => false, :proc => lambda {|record| link_to(record.contact.name, record.contact) if record.contact.present? }
  grid.column :business_name, :label => "Business", :width => 100, :sortable => false, :proc => lambda {|record| link_to(record.business.name, record.business) if record.business.present? }
  grid.column :scope_of_work_id, :hidden => true
  grid.column :markup, :hidden => true
  grid.column :notes, :hidden => true
  grid.column :shred, :hidden => true
  grid.column :printed_at, :hidden => true
  grid.column :created_at, :hidden => true
  grid.column :updated_at, :hidden => true
  grid.column :user_id, :hidden => true
  grid.column :actions, :width => 200, :sortable => false, :searchable => false, :proc => lambda {|record|
    permissioned_actions(record) do |p|
      p.show_link
      p.link('Printable', printable_quote_path(record), :show, record)
      p.edit_link
      p.destroy_link
      p.link('RFQ', request_for_quote_path(record.scope_of_work.request_for_quote_id), :show, record.scope_of_work) if record.scope_of_work.present?
      p.correspondence_link
      p.resources_link
      p.link(record.work_order.number, work_order_path(record)) if record.work_order
    end
  }
}
```

end

Hello, I have this grid in my code. Every time I need to open this grid, the results seems to be random. I need, by default, to be sort by id(number) from the highest to the lowest.

i can not see the way to do it, it seems it has a jquery that makes the sort, but I can not find it, I am new to Ruby and java.

thank you so much for your help.

It seems I am using GRIDIFY as a plugin.

Comment: What plugin are you using to generate the grid?

Comment: I am not very sure but inside the plugin files it is GRIDIFY and it seems it is the one used.

Answer (score 0):

If Quote is an active record model, can you just insert a sorting?

Rails 3:

```
Quote.order(:id).grid ....
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use this one. but I am not sure where to put it.

Comment: Hello DGM. Thanks you very  much, it seems it is working. but I need to order it from the last one to the first one (decreasing) 99, 98, 97...   I am not very familiar with the commands. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello DGM. I tryied to add it but it did not work. Here is part of the code. It is in the helper fodler under quotes_helper. But the grids keeps sorting in a random way.

def format_quote_grid!
    Quote.order('id DESC').grid  #hecho por mi
    Quote.grid.update({
    :title => "Quotes",
    :pager => true,
    :search_toolbar => :hidden,
    :resizable => false,
    :height => :auto,
    :except => [:contacts],
    :rows_per_page => 10}) { |grid|

Comment: If some one else has the same question, the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471972/default-sorting-using-jqgrid-and