# Default sorting using jqGrid and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jqgrid

Hello

I am using Ruby on rails and JQgrid. Everything works fine but when the grid load the data it is sorted in a way I don't want. I need to be sorted descendent in the ID column.
I was not the one who developed this software so I don't know exactly what to change. This code is in the helper of the quote controller and I think here is where I have to change it. Someone told me to use Quote.order('id DESC') which is in the last line. I put it in the second line but nor of them is working properly. Could someone please tell me what needs to be added in order to accomplish it? There is also code in javascript. But that is very complex. I think I don't need to change that.

I really appreciate. I have more than 2 moths trying to solve it. Thanks.

```
def format_quote_grid!
Quote.grid.update({
:title => "Quotes",
:pager => true,
:search_toolbar => :hidden,
:resizable => false,
:height => :auto,
:except => [:contacts],
:rows_per_page => 10}) { |grid|
  grid.column :id, :label => "Number", :width => 50#, :proc => lambda {|record| link_to record.number, quote_path(record) }
  grid.column :job_name, :width => 140, :proc => lambda {|record| link_to record.job_name, quote_path(record) }
  grid.column :category, :width => 60
  grid.column :needs_installation, :width => 60
  grid.column :contact_id, :hidden => true
  grid.column :business_id, :hidden => true
  grid.column :contact_name, :label => "Contact", :width => 100, :sortable => false, :proc => lambda {|record| link_to(record.contact.name, record.contact) if record.contact.present? }
  grid.column :business_name, :label => "Business", :width => 100, :sortable => false, :proc => lambda {|record| link_to(record.business.name, record.business) if record.business.present? }
  grid.column :scope_of_work_id, :hidden => true
  grid.column :markup, :hidden => true
  grid.column :notes, :hidden => true
  grid.column :shred, :hidden => true
  grid.column :printed_at, :hidden => true
  grid.column :created_at, :hidden => true
  grid.column :updated_at, :hidden => true
  grid.column :user_id, :hidden => true
  grid.column :actions, :width => 200, :sortable => false, :searchable => false, :proc => lambda {|record|
    permissioned_actions(record) do |p|
      p.show_link
      p.link('Printable', printable_quote_path(record), :show, record)
      p.edit_link
      p.destroy_link
      p.link('RFQ', request_for_quote_path(record.scope_of_work.request_for_quote_id), :show, record.scope_of_work) if record.scope_of_work.present?
      p.correspondence_link
      p.resources_link
      p.link(record.work_order.number, work_order_path(record)) if record.work_order
    end
  }
  Quote.order('id DESC')  #hecho por mi
}
  end
```

Comment: Can you please post the jQgrid javascript code you are using?

Comment: Also, are you using a rails plugin to generate the grid?  If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, from one of your earlier posts on this subject, it seems you are using [Gridify](https://github.com/linoj/gridify).

Gridify seems to support the following options:

```
:sort_by    # name of sort column of next request
:sort_order # sort direction of next request, 'asc' or 'desc' ('asc')
```

So, I would add the following just below `:except => [:contacts],`

```
:sort_by => :id,
:sort_order => :desc,
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Brian. Thank you very much for your answer. It is exactly what I needed. It seems this is a mix between GRIDIFY and jqGrid. The jqgrid is the one that apears on the html page when the page is loaded. But up to now this is a maze for me. The javascript has Gridify and JQgrid quote at the same time. I just realized it was this quote because I change the name in caption. Any way it is working right. I can not vote up yet but your answer is perfect. Thanks again.